# HTML5/CSS3 литература

Tags: html5, книги

Подскажите пожалуйста литературу о HTML5/CSS3. Хочется детально изучить нововведения.
Тут же из постов советовали книгу "Introducing HTML5". Как вам она?.
Заранее всем спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень полезный и содержательный ресурс: [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/) (проект Google) - там и примеры, и слайды, и видео.

Comment: Спасибо, ресурс хорош)

Answer (score 0):

Не так чтоб книга, но [полезные статьи по HTML5](http://htmlbook.ru/html5)

Answer (score 0):

Покопайтесь [здесь](http://www.wowebook.im/)

Answer (score 0):

Очень хорошая книга - HTML5 и CSS3 Веб-разработка по стандартам нового поколения, автор Брайан Хоган

Comment: сюдя по отзывам книга "неочень"

Comment: ИМХО, книга супер, можете скачать ее в pdf и просмотреть!

Answer (score 0):

htmlbook.ru - там и dive into html5 переведенный есть. Мне понравился ресурс.

Comment: Да ресурс знал еще раньше.. Очень хорошая большая онлайн шпоргалка